# How to difine variables as to avoid "Property must be initialized or be abstract" error in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I use Kotlin on Android Studio.

If you code as below, the "Property must be initialized or be abstract" error occurred. In the other hand, you cannot write `public val ButtonA = binding.ButtonA` inside onCreate method. In this case, as  [Learn the Kotlin programming language](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/learn) says, is it the only way to rewrite the comment place as `val ButtonA:String? = null` and write `ButtonA = binding.ButtonA` in the onCreate method?

I would not like to write as `val ButtonA = binding.ButtonA` in other method such as onClickedButtonA, so I asked. If you have other solution, I'd like to know.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val ButtonA:Button // THE ERROR OCCURED IF YOU CODE LIKE THIS.

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ButtonA = binding.ButtonA
    }
    
    fun onClickedButtonA(view:View){
        ButtonA.text = "Hoge"
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change `private val ButtonA:Button` to `private lateinit var ButtonA:Button`

Comment: If you are using binding then there is no need to do things like this. You can directly access it `binding.ButtonA?.text = "Hoge"`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Oh, I see. Thank you! I did not know it.